# Custom Hook is updating either Parent or Child component but not both

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal to to use a hook that will get the current state at any part of the application. I know we can use `useContext` for it but I've seen many libraries do the same with a **custom hook** like `useHook`. For a simple hook below, either the child or parent component updates with the new screen width size when the screen width is changed but not both together!  Here is the https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-resonance-w6qui?file=/src/App.js for the below and the demo is at: https://w6qui.csb.app/

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useHook = () => {
  const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(window.screen.width);

  window.onresize = () => setScreenWidth(window.screen.width);

  return { screenWidth };
};

function Child() {
  const { screenWidth } = useHook();

  return <div>Child ScreenWidth: {screenWidth}</div>;
}

function App() {
  const { screenWidth } = useHook();

  return (
    <div>
      Parent screenWidth: {screenWidth} <Child />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is what the output looks like. Ideally, I expect both of them to be the same width! [image]

Thanks for your help! Much appreciated if someone can clear up the concept for me, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because either the child or parent component will `override (re-declare)` call back for `window.onresize`. I suggest you should use event listener for callback re-size:

```
const useHook = () => {
    const [screenWidth, setScreenWidth] = useState(window.screen.width);

    useEffect(() => {
        function updateSize() {
            setScreenWidth(window.screen.width);
        }
        
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateSize);
        updateSize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateSize);
    }, []);

    return { screenWidth };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Works perfetly now. :)